# How to use Laravel command in browser address bar?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is it possible to use a Laravel command in browser address bar ? If yes could you please give some examples like;

```
http://yourdomain.com/Auth::logout()
http://yourdomain.com/Auth::login($user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any facades or console commands like this, but you can create simple route for this task. For example:

```
Route::get('do-logout', function() {
    auth()->logout();
});
```

The just run this code with:

```
http://yourdomain.com/do-logout
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And how can I switch or update session username with this method ?

Comment: You should create another question and explain what exactly are you trying to achieve and show some code.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960274/how-to-switch-or-update-session-username Could you please check it